# I want to use the variable I declared somewhere else but I cannot (simple sql query)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @path text;
SET @path = 'c:\bulk'

BULK INSERT [HumanResources].[Employee] FROM -- I Want to use the variable here !!
WITH (
    CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
    CODEPAGE='ACP',
    DATAFILETYPE='widechar',
    FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
    KEEPIDENTITY,
    TABLOCK
);
```

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: Atleast provide a Pseudocode

Comment: the Intellisense just tell me I cannot use @path after the FROM.

Comment: [The curse and blessings of dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Tip: When you are reading the documentation, e.g. for [`BULK INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx?ppud=4), and the syntax provided indicates that a quoted string is required, e.g. `FROM 'data_file'`, that may be your only choice. Impedisense(TM) is supposed to know that and impede your progress.  Other approaches, like dynamic SQL, may be available.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @path nvarchar(2000);

    SET @path = 'c:\bulk.(extension)';
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =

    '''BULK INSERT [HumanResources].[Employee] FROM' + @path  + '
    WITH (
        CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
        CODEPAGE=''ACP'',
        DATAFILETYPE=''widechar'',
        FIELDTERMINATOR=''\t'',
        ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'',
        KEEPIDENTITY,
        TABLOCK
    )'''

    EXECUTE sp_executesql(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this query? Uses dynamic query to execute query. Just aware of the single quotes.

```
 DECLARE @path nvarchar(2000);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000);
SET @path = 'c:\bulk.txt'

set @sql = 'BULK INSERT [HumanResources].[Employee] FROM ''' + @path + ''' WITH (CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,  CODEPAGE=''ACP'',
    DATAFILETYPE=''widechar'',
    FIELDTERMINATOR=''\t'',
    ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'',
    KEEPIDENTITY,
    TABLOCK
)'

print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```