# Variable name and string concatenate '+' error as incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

```
RESTORE DATABASE Umbraco6
FROM  DISK = 'C:\Temp\initial_db.bak'
    WITH  MOVE 'Umbraco6'     TO @db_physical_path  + '\test_data.mdf',
MOVE 'Umbraco6_log' TO  @db_physical_path + '\test_data.ldf',
REPLACE
```

In the above SQL script I get error:

> 'incorrect syntax error near '+'.

Any ideas?

Comment: What datatype is your variable?

Comment: i am using varchar datatype as below </br>declare @db_physical_path varchar(200)

Comment: **[This looks like it is related a might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212207/i-want-to-use-the-variable-i-declared-somewhere-else-but-i-cannot-simple-sql-qu#comment28431309_19212207)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @db_physical_path_data nvarchar(200)
declare @db_physical_path_log nvarchar(200)

set @db_physical_path_data = @db_physical_path + '\test_data.mdf'
set @db_physical_path_log = @db_physical_path +'\test_data.ldf'

RESTORE DATABASE Umbraco6
 FROM DISK = N'C:\Temp\initial_db.bak'
 WITH MOVE N'Umbraco6' TO @db_physical_path_data,
 MOVE N'Umbraco6_log' TO @db_physical_path_log, REPLACE
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: marc_s, thanks for the quick response, but this solution didn't work, error remains.

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work in SQL Server 2008 R2. What version of SQL are you using? And by the way: it was Jonysuise who answered.

Comment: Then try to put all the sentence restore into a nvarchar string and then run sp_executesql @var. Thanks marc_s for the tip.